# why is the required attribute in the form not working

Tags: javascript, html

Html file: index.html. Had to validate with javascript because could not get required attribute to work.  I did a sample file with a few fields and it worked, don't know why it is not working on this form. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Employee Cost</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nodep-date-input-polyfill.dist.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="css/hireCost.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/webshim/js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>

    <script>
        webshim.activeLang('en');
        webshims.polyfill('forms');
        webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;
    </script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="text">
    <div id="ribbon">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu">CPCC</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/cce">Corporate &amp; Continuing      Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://tix.cpcc.edu">CPCC Tix</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://cpccfoundation.com/">CPCC Foundation</a></li>
            <li class="accessibility"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/services/accessibility">Accessibility</a></li>
            <li class="need-help"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/services/need-help">Need Help&nbsp;
                <img alt="Need Help?" src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/help_icon.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="header-inner">
        <div id="logo"><img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/logo.png" alt="CPCC Logo"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="LSResult" id="LSResult" style="">
        <div class="LSShadow" id="LSShadow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="site-navigation">
            <li id="portaltab-about" class="plain"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/about" title="">
                About CPCC</a></li>
            <li id="portaltab-learning" class="plain"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/academics" title="">Academics</a>
            </li>
            <li id="portaltab-studentservices" class="plain"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/services" title="">Student
                Services</a></li>
            <li id="portaltab-artscommunity" class="plain"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/artscommunity" title="">Arts
                &amp; Community</a></li>
            <li id="portaltab-careerhub" class="plain"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/careerhub" title="">Career Hub</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end menu -->

    <noscript>
        <h1 class="noScriptMessage"><b>We're sorry - You must have JavaScript enabled to use Rateschedule.</b></h1>
        <h3 class="noScriptMessage">Please enable JavaScript on your browser.</h3>
    </noscript>

    <!-- Form data, all data is required, once submit is clicked, form will be validated and emcumbrance will be calculated. -->
    <form id="calculation_form" name="calculation_form" method="post">
        <h1>Rate Schedule Calculator</h1>


        <fieldset>

                <legend>Employee Information</legend>
                <div class="help-info">
                    <strong>Note:</strong> Non-Exempt employees will submit and be paid from timesheets.  Instructors will submit and be paid from contact hour reports.
                </div>
                <dl>
                    <dt><label for="empId">Employee ID:</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" id="empId" pattern="[0-9]{7}" placeholder="Employee ID" value="" required />
                    </dd>

                    <dt><label for="fName">First Name:</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" id="fName" required placeholder="First Name" value="" /></dd>

                    <dt><label for="lName">Last Name</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" id="lName" required placeholder="Last Name" value="" /></dd>

                    <dt><label for="posNum">Position Number</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" id="posNum" required placeholder="Position Number" value="" /></dd>

                    <dt><label for="posTitle">Position Title</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" id="posTitle" required placeholder="Position Title" value="" /></dd>

                    <dt><label for="empType">Employee Type</label></dt>
                    <dd><select id="empType" name="empType">
                        <option value="" selected>Select Employee Type:</option>
                        <option value="Hourly Pay Rate (Non Exempt Employees)">Hourly Pay Rate (Non Exempt Employees)
                        </option>
                        <option value="Contact Hour Pay Rate (Exempt Instructors)">Contact Hour Pay Rate (Exempt
                            Instructors)
                        </option>
                    </select></dd>

                    <dt><label for="sDate">Start date</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="date" id="sDate" required/></dd>
                    <dt><label for="cDate">End date</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="date" id="cDate" required/></dd>
                </dl>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Budgeting Worksheet</legend>
            <div class="help-info">
                <strong>Important:</strong> Be aware that submitting a rate sheet beyond the bounds of the current fiscal year will encumber funds for the following year.
            </div>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="glAcct">GL Account:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="glAcct" required placeholder="GL Account" value=""/></dd>

                <dt><label for="rate">Hourly rate:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="number" id="rate" required placeholder="Hourly rate" value=""/></dd>

                <dt><label for="hours">Estimated Monthly Hours:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="number" id="hours" required placeholder="Monthly Hours" value=""/></dd>

                <dd><input type="hidden" id="comp" value=""/></dd>
            </dl>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Supervisor Information</legend>
            <div class="help-info">
                Please enter the information for the supervisor of the position described in this Rate Schedule.
            </div>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="supervisor">Supervisor Name:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="supervisor" required placeholder="Supervisor Name" value=""/></dd>

                <dt><label for="phone">Phone Extension:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="phone" pattern="[0-9]{4}" required placeholder="Phone Extension" value=""/>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <p>
        <button class="button" id="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
        <button class="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul id="footer-navigation">
            <li><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/humanresources/employment">
                <img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/briefcase_icon.png"
                     alt="Jobs at CPCC"></a><br>
                <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/humanresources/employment">Jobs at CPCC</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/attending/catalog">
                <img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/catalog_icon.png"
                     alt="College Catalog"></a><br>
                <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/attending/catalog">College Catalog</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/college-safety">
                <img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/icon_college_safety.png"
                     alt="College Safety"></a><br>
                <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/college-safety">Safety</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/site-map">
                <img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/sitemap_icon.png" alt="Site Map"></a><br>
                <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/site-map">Site Map</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://inside.cpcc.edu/">
                <img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/employee_icon.png"
                     alt="Employee Intranet"></a><br>
                <a href="http://inside.cpcc.edu/">Employee Intranet</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/services/online-services">
                <img id="tester" src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/globe_icon.png"
                     alt="Online Services"></a><br>
                <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/services/online-services">Online Services</a></li>
            <li class="last">
                <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/contact-us">
                    <img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/contact_icon.png"
                         alt="Contact Us"></a><br>
                <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="footer-links"><a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/browsers/supported-browsers">Supported Browsers</a> /
            <a href="http://www.cpcc.edu/services/accessibility">Accessibility</a><br>Central Piedmont Community College
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Below is the format for the printable form.  Again Handlebars is used to update the page. -->
<div id="printable">
    <div class="header-inner">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="http://www.cpcc.edu/++resource++theme.www.images/logo.png" alt="CPCC Logo"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <h3>Rate Schedule</h3>
    <div class="help-employee-info">
        <p>Note: Non-Exempt employees will submit and be paid from timesheets.
            <br>Instructors will submit and be paid from contact hour reports.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3> Employee Information</h3>
    <dl class="data">
        <dt>Employee ID:</dt>
        <dd>{{empId}}</dd>
        <dt>First name:</dt>
        <dd>{{fName}}</dd>
        <dt>Last name:</dt>
        <dd>{{lName}}</dd>
        <dt>Position number:</dt>
        <dd>{{posNum}}</dd>
        <dt>Position title:</dt>
        <dd>{{posTitle}}</dd>
        <dt>Employee Type:</dt>
        <dd>{{empType}}</dd>
    </dl>
    <h3>Budgeting Worksheet</h3>

    <dl class="data">

        <dt>GL Account:</dt>
        <dd>{{glAcct}}</dd>
        <dt>Start date:</dt>
        <dd>{{sDate}}</dd>
        <dt>End date:</dt>
        <dd>{{cDate}}</dd>
        <dt>Hourly rate:</dt>
        <dd>{{rate}}</dd>
        <dt>Estimated Monthly Hours:</dt>
        <dd>{{hours}}</dd>
    </dl>
    <h3>Calculated Values</h3>
    <dl class="data">
        <dt>Estimated Encumbrance for Current Fiscal Year:</dt>
        <dd>{{comp}}</dd>
    </dl>

    <div>
        <h3>Authorization:</h3>
        <div class="signature-box"></div>
        <div id="supervisor-print">
            <span>{{supervisor}}</span>
            <span>Phone Extension: {{phone}}</span>
            <span>Date</span>
        </div>
        <div class="help-employee-info">
            <p>Please sign, date and submit to Human Resources.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="calculateHireCost.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>


Javascript file: calculateHireCost.js
// This program will calculate the cost of hiring personal for the dates, rate, and hours specified. The program will
// also retain values for a print friendly page once the calculate/submit button is pressed.  Handlebars is used to
// update the page with the printable version of the information.
// Run fuction validateForm when the submit button is clicked. Once the form is validated, ValidateForm will call the
// function process_form.  The only validation is that a field is required and end date is greater than start date.
// Run function reset_form when reset button is clicked.

$("#submit").bind( "click", function() { validateForm() });
$("#reset").bind( "click", function() { reset_form() });

var source = $("#printable").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#sDate').val("");
    $('#cDate').val("");

    initialize_dates();
})

// Validate fields to confirm no null values.  If field is blank or null, return alert message requesting input from
// the user.  If all fields are valid, run process_form.

function validateForm() {

    var empId = document.forms["calculation_form"]["empId"].value;
    var fName = document.forms["calculation_form"]["fName"].value;
    var lName = document.forms["calculation_form"]["lName"].value;
    var posNum = document.forms["calculation_form"]["posNum"].value;
    var posTitle = document.forms["calculation_form"]["posTitle"].value;
    var empType = document.forms["calculation_form"]["empType"].value;
    var sDate = document.forms["calculation_form"]["sDate"].value;
    var cDate = document.forms["calculation_form"]["cDate"].value;
    var glAcct = document.forms["calculation_form"]["glAcct"].value;
    var rate = document.forms["calculation_form"]["rate"].value;
    var hours = document.forms["calculation_form"]["hours"].value;
    var supervisor = document.forms["calculation_form"]["supervisor"].value;
    var phone = document.forms["calculation_form"]["phone"].value;

    if (empId == null || empId == "") {
        alert("Employee Id must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (fName == null || fName == "") {
        alert("First name must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (lName == null || lName == "") {
        alert("Last name must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (posNum == null || posNum == "") {
        alert("Position number must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (posTitle == null || posTitle == "") {
        alert("Position title must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (empType == null || empType == "") {
        alert("Employee Type must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (sDate == null || sDate == "") {
        alert("A start date must be selected");
        return false;
    }
    if (cDate == null || cDate == "") {
        alert("An end date must be selected");
        return false;
    }
    if (glAcct == null || glAcct == "") {
        alert("GL Account must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (rate == null || rate == "") {
        alert("An hourly rate must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (hours == null || hours == "") {
        alert("The estimated monthly hours must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (supervisor == null || supervisor == "") {
        alert("Supervisor's name must be entered");
        return false;
    }
    if (phone == null || phone == "") {
        alert("Phone extension must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    process_form();
}

// process_form will save entered and calculated values to be re-displayed in a print friendly form
// on the page.  This function will call the calculate function to calculate the Yearly Emcumbrance.

function process_form()
{
    var empId = $("#empId").val();
    var fName = $("#fName").val();
    var lName = $("#lName").val();
    var posNum = $("#posNum").val();
    var posTitle = $("#posTitle").val();
    var empType = $("#empType").val();

    var glAcct = $("#glAcct").val();
    var sDate = $("#sDate").val();
    var cDate = $("#cDate").val();
    var rate = $("#rate").val();
    var hours = $("#hours").val();

    var supervisor = $("#supervisor").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();

    console.log(sDate);
    console.log(cDate);
    console.log(hours);
    console.log(rate);

    // verify end date is greater than start date.
    if (sDate < cDate)
    {
        // store compensation

        $("#comp").val(calculate(sDate, cDate));
        var comp = $("#comp").val();
        //  data variable will be used by handlebars to create printable version of page.
        var data = {
            'empId': empId,
            'fName': fName,
            'lName': lName,
            'posNum': posNum,
            'posTitle': posTitle,
            'empType': empType,
            'glAcct': glAcct,
            'sDate': sDate,
            'cDate': cDate,
            'rate': rate,
            'hours': hours,
            'comp': comp,
            'supervisor': supervisor,
            'phone': phone,
        }

        console.log(sDate);
        console.log(cDate);
        console.log(hours);
        console.log(rate);

        // replace div id=="text" with printable version of "data".
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = template(data);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('End date must be later than start date. Please adjust dates.');
    }
}

// This function will calculate the yearly encumbrance. The number of hours x rate x months.  The months between
// function will determine the number of months.

function calculate(sDate,cDate)
{
    // convert date string to date

    var newdate1 = new Date(sDate);
    var newdate2 = new Date(cDate);

    newdate1.setDate(newdate1.getDate() + 2);
    newdate2.setDate(newdate2.getDate() + 2);


    var dd1 = newdate1.getDate();
    var mm1 = newdate1.getMonth() + 1;
    var y1 = newdate1.getFullYear();

    var dd2 = newdate2.getDate();
    var mm2 = newdate2.getMonth() + 1;
    var y2 = newdate2.getFullYear();


    var date1 = mm1 + '-' + dd1 + '-' + y1;
    var date2 = mm2 + '-' + dd2 + '-' + y2;

    var date1 = new Date(date1);
    var date2 = new Date(date2);

    date1 = moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    date2 = moment(date2).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    var rate = $("#rate").val();
    var hours = $("#hours").val();
    console.log(date1);
    console.log(date2);

    // retrieve number of months
    var months = monthsBetween(date1, date2);

    console.log(months);

    // calculate total hours and compensation
    var comp = rate * hours * months;

    console.log(comp);
    return comp;
}

// This function calculates the number of months between the two dates. Partial months will be counted as
// a whole month.  If the end date is 8/1/20xx, then August will count as one month.  Since this is for
// yearly budgeting, the number of months have a max of 12.  If a two year period is entered, it will be
// reduced from 24 to 12 months.

function monthsBetween(date1, date2)
{
    date1 = new Date(date1);
    date2 = new Date(date2);

    var date1Month = date1.getMonth();
    var date2Month = date2.getMonth();
    var date1Year = date1.getFullYear();
    var date2Year = date2.getFullYear();
    var date2Date = date2.getDate();
    var months = 0;

    if (date1 < date2) {

        var i = new Date(date1);
        while ((i <= date2) && (months < 12)) {

            if (date1Month == 11) {
                months++;
                date1Year++;
                date1Month = 00;
                i.setDate(01);
                i.setFullYear(date1Year);
                i.setMonth(00);
            }
            else {
                months++;
                date1Month++;
                i.setDate(01);
                i.setMonth(date1Month);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('End date must be later than start date. Please adjust dates.');
    }
    if (months == 0)
    {
        months = 1;
    }
    if (date2Date == 01)
    {
        months++;
    }
    if (months > 12)
    {
        months = 12;
    }
    return months;
}

function reset_form()
{
    $("#empId").val("");
    $("#fName").val("");
    $("#lName").val("");
    $("#posNum").val("");
    $("#posTitle").val("");
    $("#empType").val("");
    $("#glAcct").val("");
    $("#sDate").val("");
    $("#cDate").val("");
    $("#rate").val(0);
    $("#hours").val(0);
    $("#comp").val(0);

    $("#supervisor").val("");
    $("#phone").val("");

    initialize_dates();
}
function set_end_date_per_start_date(mode) {
    //
    // Seed the end date based on the start date's month.  If after May, push
    // the end date's year out to next year.
    //
    if (mode == 'initial')
    {
        startDate = new Date();
        console.log(startDate);
    }
    else
    {
        currentStartDate = $("#sDate").val();
        console.log(currentStartDate);
        parts = currentStartDate.value.split("/");
        startDate = new Date(parseInt(parts[2]),(parseInt(parts[0])),parseInt(parts[1]));
        console.log(startDate);
    }
    if (startDate.getMonth() > 4)
    {
        console.log(startDate);
        endDate = new Date((startDate.getFullYear() + 1), 4, 31);
        console.log(endDate);
    }
    else
    {
        endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), 4, 31);
        console.log(endDate);
    }

    console.log(startDate.getMonth());
    console.log(startDate.getDate());
    startDateString = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    $("#sDate").val(startDateString);
    console.log($("#sDate").val());

    console.log(startDate.getMonth());
    console.log(startDate.getDate());
    console.log(endDate.getMonth());
    console.log(endDate.getDate());
    endDateString = moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    $("#cDate").val(endDateString);
    console.log($("#cDate").val());
    console.log(endDate.getMonth());
    console.log(endDate.getDate());

}

function initialize_dates() {
    //
    // Seed with today's date.
    //
    set_end_date_per_start_date('initial');
}
```

Comment: on which browser you are testing this ?

Comment: You should always validate with JavaScript anyway. You shouldn't assume the browser will respect the required tag. HTML5 standards are not 100% implemented across all existing browsers.

Comment: where are your input's `name` attributes? `required` might want `name`

Comment: See here http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: I am testing on chrome and safari. I will add name attribute and see if that helps. Thanks.